# Unable logon sql instanced

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, user-accounts

Recently I changed a password for the account and now I am unable to run instances on the SQL server. I got error0x8007042d. What is more interesting the same credentials are working on another sql server. Another interesting thing is no matter what credentials I use from my domain I got the same error. Can you please guide where the problem lies?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are both servers pointing to the same domain controller? If not, what is the replication time between them? Perhaps it's working on the other server because the password was reset on the DC it's pointing at.

Also check the server is actually joined to the domain properly, has a machine account in AD, the account you're trying to use isn't locked out/disabled, etc.

Another possibility could be Group Policy settings, check both servers are in the same OU, or have the same policy applied.

Comment: Hi, yes both servers are on the same OU in AD .Also those servers are VM's which run on the  common machine. ALso account is active and fine i checked that as well.

Comment: Check in Group Policy (gpedit.msc) Computer Configuration --> Windows Settings --> Security Settings --> Local Policies --> User Rights Assignment --> Log on as a service

See if the account, or a group it's a member of, is in that setting. Also I'm assuming it's the same account for both servers?

Comment: Same account for both yes, ofcourse i log using my own credentials. Also i chekced where you point me and i do not see this account here only one group and everything is gray (probably i do not have authorization to do anything there)

Comment: And this account is not a member of this group :(

Comment: I think you helped with this track. thanks for guidence !